# Build React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have this problem when trying to install some items

example:yarn add react-navigation;

```
warning " > react-native-paper@3.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-vector- 
icons@*".
[5/5]   Building fresh packages...
[-/9] ⠈ waiting...
[6/9] ⠈ lib-jitsi-meet
[7/9] ⠁ node-sass
[8/9] ⠁ ejs
error /node_modules/lib-jitsi-meet: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: webpack -p
Arguments:
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in error you have to install `react-native-vector-icons`, which is the dependency of the `react-native-paper`. So go first install `react-native-vector-icon` and then try to install another package. [Here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) is the documentation of how to install react-native-vector-icon.